# Converting hours in decimal format

Tags: java

I've tried mutliple solutions to this problem but I can't seem to get it.

I have time in decimal format, which is in hours. I want to make it much cleaner by changing it into a DD:HH:MM:SS format.

### Example:

<strike>10.89 hours == 10 hours, 53 minutes, 40 seconds</strike>

**EDIT**: 10.894945454545455 == 10 hours, 53 minutes, 40 seconds

### What I've tried:

```
int hours = (int) ((finalBuildTime) % 1);
int minutes = (int) ((finalBuildTime * (60*60)) % 60);
int seconds = (int) ((finalBuildTime * 3600) % 60);

return String.format("%s(h) %s(m) %s(s)", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Which returned: `0(h) 41(m) 41(s)`

Any suggestions?

Comment: @zod if you look above I never claimed that .89 was 89 minutes. COPIED VERBATIM: "10.89 hours == 10 hours, 53 minutes, 40 seconds"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. There is no need to do a modular on minutes.
2. Your calculation of minutes should just multiply by 60, not (60*60)

   ```
   double finalBuildTime = 10.89;
   int hours = (int) finalBuildTime;
   int minutes = (int) (finalBuildTime * 60) % 60;
   int seconds = (int) (finalBuildTime * (60*60)) % 60;

   System.out.println(String.format("%s(h) %s(m) %s(s)", hours, minutes, seconds));
   ```

This code gives you the correct output

```
10(h) 53(m) 24(s)
```

I believe your expected output of 40 seconds is incorrect.  It should be 24 seconds.

```
(53*60 + 24)/(60*60) = 0.89
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It seems that the "ungarbled" time I was cross referencing the output with was messed up so that lead to the difference between 24 and 40 seconds. Nonetheless, your solution was correct.

Comment: Actually just looked over that calculations myself. The actually double was 10.894945454545455 which should indeed be 10h 53m 41s.

Comment: how to apply reverse engineering for this ???
like:
input : 2:30
expected output : 2.5

Answer (score 3):

Here is a complete implementation:

```
package test.std.java;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(GetReadableTime(10.89));
    }

    //Prints outs HH:MM:SS
    public static String GetReadableTime(double finalBuildTime){

        int hours = (int) Math.floor(finalBuildTime);
        int remainderInSeconds = (int)(3600.0* (finalBuildTime - Math.floor(finalBuildTime)) );
        int seconds = remainderInSeconds % 60;
        int minutes = remainderInSeconds / 60;
        return  String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds); 
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe (int) finalBuildTime is equivalent to (int) Math.floor(finalBuildTime).  Additionally you can refer to the variable hours when calculating seconds instead of doing the floor again.

Comment: Absolutely agree, of course. It just makes it easier for the newbies to understand... Making the truncation part more explicit.

Comment: Another great answer. Also helps that you are "spelling out" the calculations.

Comment: What would the reverse process of converting from hours to decimals be like?

Answer (score 2):

First part of rgettman is true :

```
float finalBuildTime = 10.89;
int hours = (int) finalBuildTime; // 10 ok
```

But (int) ((10.89 * (60 *60)) / 60) = 683 which is not what you want : it is the direct conversion of `finalBuildTime` in minutes

```
int minutes = (int) ((finalBuildTime - hours) * 60); // 53 ok
int seconds = (int) ((finalBuildTime - hours) * 3600 - minutes * 60 + 0.5); // 24 ok
```

I've added 0.5 for the seconds computation to round to the nearest second rather than truncate. For your example it is no use because your time is an integer number of seconds.

And the number of seconds **is** `24 seconds = 0.4 minutes`

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are correct, but in case it helps you (or someone else who stumbles across this) it is a lot easier to use a library like [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) to do this. Here is a solution to your problem using Joda-Time 2.3:

```
double buildDurationInHours = 10.89;
long buildDurationInMilliseconds = new Double(DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_HOUR * buildDurationInHours).longValue();
Period period = new Period(buildDurationInMilliseconds);
System.out.println("The build took "
        + period.getDays() + " days, "
        + period.getHours() + " hours, "
        + period.getMinutes() + " minutes, and "
        + period.getSeconds() + " seconds.");
```

Output:

```
The build took 0 days, 10 hours, 53 minutes, and 24 seconds.
```

This way you don't have to deal directly with calculating the hours, minutes, seconds, etc.

Comment: Although I like the suggestion of using Joda-Time, in order for this question to help the user, you will need to help him convert a decimal number into milliseconds.

Comment: @JustinKSU True, I'll edit that in. Again Joda-Time helps with this by providing `DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_HOUR`. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Looks good.  Instead of using BigDecimal, why not use the Double class?  new Double(DateTimeConstants.MILLIS_PER_HOUR * buildDurationInHours).longValue();

Answer (score 2):

I assume finalBuildTime is a double. You just have to do :

```
int hours = (int)finalBuildTime;
int minutes = (int)((finalBuildTime - hours) * 60);
int seconds = (int)((((finalBuildTime - hours) * 60) - minutes ) * 60);
```

Comment: Another great solution. P.S. There is a missing semicolon at the end of the minutes calculation. Sorry for being nitpicky. Just thinking ahead if anyone stumbles across this.

Answer (score 1):

1. (int) rounds down. Therefore, (int)(finalBuildTime) gives you hours.
2. Since 60 times 60 is 3600, your seconds and minutes calculations are the same.
3. To find the minutes and seconds, I would observe that the 10.89 hours in your example is 10 hours and 0.89 hours. I would first calculate how many minutes is in 0.89 hours.(the part after the decimal point) That would be 0.89 times 60. Again, since this number should always be less than 60, casting(therefore, rounding down) the number to an (int) gives you minutes. Therefore, for minutes, it is int minutes = (int)((finalBuildTime-hours)*60);
4. You can keep the rest of your code.